# How to get multiple query parameters in Caveman

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, caveman2

My code works well in REPL, but it does not get the second value in my web application.

eg `(?vehicle=bike&vehicle=car)`

#### what I tried

when I do

- CL-USER>  `(setf |vehicle| '(a b c)`
- CL-USER>

  `` (let ((|vehicle| (multival-plist:getf-all `(:|vehicle| ,|vehicle|) :|vehicle|)))
         (print (alexandria:flatten (list :vehicle |vehicle|)))) ``

which result the desired output `(:VEHICLE A B C)`

but when I submit my form

```
<form action="/checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="car"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

to my route

```
@route GET "/checkbox"
(lambda (&key |vehicle|)
  (let ((|vehicle| (multival-plist:getf-all `(:|vehicle| ,|vehicle|) :|vehicle|)))
    (format nil "~a" (list :vehicle (alexandria:flatten |vehicle|)))))
```

actually I render the result to djula template, but for testing I use `format` instead.

```
<ul>
    {% for a in vehicle %}
        <li>{{ a }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

it resulted only `(VEHICLE (bike))` even two of them checked, resulting in

- bike

### what I expect to happen

the output should

- bike
- car

I will use 16 checkboxes in my app, this will result to very long link, any suggestion to make the link short.

PS: I use Hunchentoot server and Caveman2 web framework.

Comment: I think you should look at how to access query parameters. See the [readme](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman/blob/master/README.markdown#structured-querypost-parameters) and details on [this issue](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman/issues/22).

Comment: Yes, I have read that readme before post my question here, even I have [implemented](https://gitlab.com/azzamsa/belajar-web) the structured query, but now the case is if the form input has the same name e.g checkbox. this is the [caveman1 explanation](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman/blob/master/README.v1.markdown#multiple-values-in-params) using multiple value in params but it doesn't help me.

Comment: [this is one](https://github.com/quickdocs/quickdocs-server) of web app built with caveman2, but it does not use checkbox at all, so I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Stil there is no solution for this problem, but [my dirty hack](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman/issues/97) is: add square brackets to the form name, then use `_parsed` as `&key` then manipulating the result.

Comment: I think that is not dirty, but maybe the only way to do it.  I must admit that I am not too fond of caveman2 after splashing around in it a bit now.

Comment: Thank lot for your help, Svante. Some of "big" CL web app are [Wigflip](http://wigflip.com/) and [Kindista](https://github.com/kindista/kindista/blob/master/kindista.asd), both of them use hunchentoot directly, and [Quickdocs](https://github.com/quickdocs/quickdocs-server) use Caveman2.

Comment: It also seems this is the way to do it. At least in Lucerne there is a nice `with-params` macro. (nice finding for Kindista)

Answer (score 0):

change `name=vehicle`  to `name=vehicle[]` in the html and caveman2 will parse this as a list of values giving the list `("bike" "car")` when both checked as the value of `vehicle`.